# Beginner Java if else range statement

Tags: java, if-statement, floating-point

I'm trying to find the total cost of delivery charge base on parcel weight.

Why when I put anything more than 2.5 it'll came out as 2 answers?

E.g:

```
Please enter parcelweight
3
The charge is 8.55
The charge is 7.3500000000000005
```

The corresponding code is:

```
    if(parcelweight  < 2.5)
   {
       System.out.println("The charge is" +parcelweight*3.5);      

   }
   else {

        if((parcelweight >=2.5 && parcelweight <=5));
        {
            System.out.println("The charge is" +parcelweight*2.85);
        }

        if(parcelweight > 5);
        { 
            System.out.println("The charge is" +parcelweight*2.45);
        }
   }
```

Comment: This is not a float comparison mismatch. No matter what the value is, it can't compare > f and <= f at the same time. And 3 never compares > 5, no matter which kind of floating point variable is used.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a `else` after removing `;` in if(....`);` like this:

```
   else if(parcelweight > 5)
```